Double check that Discrete Fourier Transform plot is right
Link to saxophone file
Link to clarinet file
I'm trying to transform a file containing a soundwave. I just want to make sure that my transform looks right because it doesn't look right to me.
Hopefully my links work to obtain the files, but I will post the problem and plots I've made.

Code for Part B:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos, sqrt, exp, sin, pi, array, real, imag
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # import 3D axes
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, rfft, dct, dst, idct, irfft
sax=np.loadtxt('saxophone.txt')
clar=np.loadtxt('clarinet.txt')

FT1=rfft(sax)
FT2=rfft(clar)
tsax=np.linspace(0,len(FT1)/44100,len(FT1))
tclar=np.linspace(0,len(FT2)/44100,len(FT2))
plt.plot(tsax,real(FT1))
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.title('Saxophone Soundwave Discrete Fourier Transform')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(tclar,real(FT2))
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.title('Clarinet Soundwave Discrete Fourier Transform')
plt.show()  


Code for Part A & C:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos, sqrt, exp, sin, pi, array, real, imag
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D   # import 3D axes
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, rfft, dct, dst, idct, irfft
sax=np.loadtxt('saxophone.txt')
clar=np.loadtxt('clarinet.txt')

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.25)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=1)
FT1=rfft(sax)
FT2=rfft(clar)
N=len(FT1)
tsax=np.linspace(0,len(FT1)/44100,len(FT1))
tclar=np.linspace(0,len(FT2)/44100,len(FT2))
tau=tsax\[1\]
freq=array(\[k/(2\*N\*tau) for k in range(N)\])
tsax=np.linspace(0,len(sax)/44100,len(sax))
tclar=np.linspace(0,len(clar)/44100,len(clar))
plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(tsax, sax)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.title('Saxophone Soundwave')
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(tclar, clar)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.title('Clarinet Soundwave')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(freq/1000, abs(real(FT1)))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
plt.title('Saxophone Soundwave Discrete Fourier Transform Coefficients vs Frequency')
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(freq/1000, abs(real(FT2)))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
plt.title('Clarinet Soundwave Discrete Fourier Transform Coefficients vs Frequency')
plt.show()  



I was expecting the FFT plot to be more spread out rather than it being so concentrated in such a small region for the Fourier Transformation. I made sure I used the right functions and that it did what it was suppose to do which seems like it did.  I made sure my time step tau was right and I think it is. The sample rate is 44100Hz so tau should be 1/44100 or the first nonzero point in the time array. The code looks right yet the plot feels wrong.
Hopefully someone is able to confirm or deny my plots.

This is a site about programming, we really do have a simple way to format code. Please [edit] your post with appropriate formatting so we can read it as intended. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for help.

To put your mind at ease, so you can safely say the data is being read and plotted correctly. I class you may have seen plots that only went up to a ~5kHz. Try plotting just the N Frequency bins. Also, Remember you are looking at magnitude you may also want to plot dB by taking 20*log10(abs(abs(FT1))). Ask your tutor for a deeper insight.
